# What is the best way to check programatically if DLL/EXE file is signed with authenticode?

Tags: authenticode

I do not want to verify the certificate. I want to use this on a build server to check all files and list the one that we may have forgot to sign.

Comment: Which language are you intending to use for that - Perl, Batch, PowerShell, ...?

Comment: We already use C#, PowerShell and Python in the build process. But most things would work I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the [`Get-AuthenticodeSignature`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347607.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet? The description says:

> If the file is not signed, the information is retrieved, but the fields are blank.

Comment: Be aware that get-authenticodesignature will return "NOTsigned" for files that are catalog signed rather than PE signed. See http://www.itcookbook.net/blog/get-authenticodesignaturedoesnt

Comment: @quux the link you provided does not point to any valid link about authenticode.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way:

The WinVerifyTrust API can be used to verify the signature of a portable executable file.

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use node implementation of WinVerifyTrust API vid npm package `sign-check`:

```
npm install -g sign-check
sign-check 'path/to/file'
```